# Cannot specify starting glm parameters in svyglm with factor variables, R survey package

Tags: r, survey

I am working with a weighted analysis and using the `svyglm` to analyze data from a complex weighting scheme for non-response. I want to fit a log-binomial model to estimate prevalence ratios which fits in most cases by specifying `binomial(link=log)` as the family. However, in the cases when the default fitter is not able to find a starting set of coefficients, I find a convenient set that works in most cases is setting `Start <- c(log(mean(response.var)), rep(0, ncov))`.

When I supply `start` to the `svyglm` function in the `survey` package, R is throwing an error that I cannot seem to parse. It seems to be whenever one of the covariates is a factor.

Example:

```
library(survey)
data(api)
apistrat$qmeal <- with(apistrat, cut(meals, quantile(meals)))
dstrat<-svydesign(id=~1,strata=~stype, weights=~pw, data=apistrat, fpc=~fpc)
```

And an example of the GLM in question, modeling something nonsensical to reproduce the error:

```
> svyglm(awards ~ qmeal +emer, family=quasibinomial(link=log), design=dstrat)
Error: no valid set of coefficients has been found: please supply starting values
```

Okay... So I specify: `Start <- c(log(mean(api$awards, na.rm=T)), 0, 0, 0, 0)`

```
> svyglm(awards ~ cut(meals, quantile(meals)) +emer, family=quasibinomial, design=dstrat, start=start)

 > svyglm(awards ~ qmeal +emer, family=quasibinomial(link=log), design=dstrat, start=start)
Error in glm.fit(x = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1,  : 
  length of 'start' should equal 5 and correspond to initial coefs for c("(Intercept)", "qmeal(20.8,39.5]", "qmeal(39.5,69]", "qmeal(69,100]", , "emer")
```

Interestingly, the length of `start` IS 5. I further note that `svyglm` consistently produces an extra `,` (look between the last qmeal variable and "emer") with missing entries. This has no such problem when supplying to standard `glm`:

```
glm(awards ~ qmeal +emer, family=quasibinomial(link=log), data=apistrat, start=start)
```

produces the right output:

```
Call:  glm(formula = awards ~ qmeal + emer, family = quasibinomial(link = log), 
    data = apistrat, start = start)

Coefficients:
     (Intercept)  qmeal(20.8,39.5]    qmeal(39.5,69]     qmeal(69,100]              emer  
        -0.59276           0.13058           0.31311           0.24698          -0.01389  

Degrees of Freedom: 198 Total (i.e. Null);  194 Residual
  (1 observation deleted due to missingness)
Null Deviance:      272.7 
Residual Deviance: 265.7    AIC: NA
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There appears to be a problem with the way `glm` is called inside `svyglm`. Replacing the vector name `start` with anything (e.g., `x`) that does not match with the argument names of `svyglm` solves the problem.

Comment: That is a very peculiar wrinkle indeed! Very surprising considering the variety of other situations in which it works just fine: e.g. normal glm, or survey glm without factor covariates.

Comment: @AdamO, actually it doesn't seem to be related to the choice of the covariates or the family. I'll report it as a bug.

Answer (score 2):

Your code doesn't actually run, but if I instead do

`start <- c(log(mean(apistrat$awards=="Yes", na.rm=T)), 0, 0, 0, 0)`

I do get the error you're asking about.  It happens because the call to `glm` looks up its arguments in the design object (deliberately) and then inside `svyglm` (not deliberately). The formal argument `start` isn't visible there.  But `start` is the name of a function in the `stats` package, and because of complicated reasons[1] that's what you get as the argument. It doesn't have length 5. The stray comma is spurious[2]

A work-around is to specify the `start` argument explicitly rather than as a variable, so it doesn't need lookup 

`svyglm(awards ~ qmeal +emer, family=quasibinomial(link=log), design=dstrat, start=c(log(mean(apistrat$awards=="Yes", na.rm=T)), 0, 0, 0, 0))`

Another work-around is to specify something that isn't the name of an existing function, so lookup moves on to the next level and finds your variable. For example, these both work for me:

`initial <- c(log(mean(apistrat$awards=="Yes", na.rm=T)), 0, 0, 0, 0)
svyglm(awards ~ qmeal +emer, family=quasibinomial(link=log), design=dstrat, start=initial)
rose <- c(log(mean(apistrat$awards=="Yes", na.rm=T)), 0, 0, 0, 0)
svyglm(awards ~ qmeal +emer, family=quasibinomial(link=log), design=dstrat, start=rose)`

I'll try to fix this for the next version.

[1] No, I couldn't be more precise without running a bunch of experiments. They're complicated.

[2] `glm.fit` uses `deparse` to turn the vector of names into a string, and the vector is long enough to break over two lines, and that's where the comma comes from. If the variable were called `m` rather than `qmeal` you wouldn't get the comma. You could argue that was a bug in `glm.fit`, but you'd probably expend more effort than it was worth.

Comment: (+1) Your explanation is more than sufficient; using a non-conflicting name solved my problem for the short term. Inside of functions, even this does not work because of the environment, so I have to use the explicit approach as you say. It is also reassuring to understand the, extra, commas, in the error code. You can see why those, in addition to R barking that my "start" was of wrong length, led me down the wrong debugging rabbit-hole.